# Selenium Java: sort numbers in Collection low to high

Tags: java, sorting, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
    driver.get("www.exmpale.com");
    Thread.sleep(7000);
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".side-tab.side-generator")).click();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    Thread.sleep(30000);
    // to find the 5 numbers in list1 and list 2 present in the header and
    // add them in the list
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

        numberList1
                .add(
                        driver
                        .findElements(By.cssSelector(".generated-line"))
                        .get(0)
                        .findElements(
                                By.cssSelector(".generated-ball.animated.bounceIn>div")                     
                                )

                        .get(i).getText()
                        );
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("lotto-frame-games")));

// to find the numbers in the 2 boxes and add them in comparelist1 and
// comparelist2
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

    compareList1
            .add(driver
                    .findElements(
                            By.cssSelector(".select_num_col_part"))
                    .get(0)
                    .findElements(By.cssSelector(".main_active, .extra_active"))
                    .get(i).getText());


//to sort the lists so that lists can be compared easily.
Collections.sort(numberList1);
Collections.sort(compareList1);
System.out.println(numberList1.toString());
System.out.println(compareList1.toString());
```

Result:

```
 [13, 16, 27, 34, 5, 7, 7]
 [13, 16, 27, 34, 5, 7, 7]
```

I want that the sort will work from low to high, how can I do it?

Comment: You need to convert your string to an integer and put it into a List<Integer> to get a proper sort.

Answer (score 0):

You are already calling `Collections.sort(numberList1);` and thus, sorting your `List`.

However, your `numberList1` contains `String`s. If you use generics you immediately see this where you create the list. It will be something like this `List<String> numberList1 = new ...`.

Thus, the sorting will be `lexicographic`, as if you would sort text. That's why `12` comes before `3`, the first character `1` of `12` is smaller than `3` and so on.

You simply need to change your list to a list of integer: `List<Integer>`. Then your sorting will be as you want. You can transform `String`s to `Integer`s by using `Integer.parseInt(text)` or `new Integer(text)`.

Cheers